# Is it possible to mock a database call or an Api call in a stress test with Gatling?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, gatling

I have two microservices written with Spring boot and Java working in a system. The second microservice calls a database and returns a response to the first microservice. I am writing a stress test for this system with Gatling. This stress test will call the first microservice, and the second microservice will be called by the first microservice. I need to avoid the database call at this moment. Is there any way I can mock the database call in this stress test? If mocking database of second microservice is not possible, mocking the whole second microservice call will work too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i too am curiuos

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old post but if you didn't find an answer

Spring conditional expressions and profiles could help you.

In your microservice app you could make a new spring profile for your gatling tests that initiate a database mock service instead of a real one when a certain property is true (eg: test.data.mock=true).

[Check this documentation for Conditionnal properties](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/)

[This for profiles](http://baeldung.com/spring-profiles)